# Pre-1985 polluted Earth novel - hopeful/mixed ending

Tags: story-identification, novel, apocalypse

In the early 1980s I glanced at a paperback novel at a library.  In it Earth and its atmosphere were a polluted mess, with humanity and all life near extinction.  But, somewhat miraculously, a massive rainstorm (a second Great Flood was the symbolism, I suspect) cleaned the air and land and water. But as the remaining people gaze in wonder at the newly clean world, someone (the protagonist?) notices someone smoking and sees the cigarette smoke heading up into the sky - a sign that it will all happen again.

I don't recall anything about the main plot - suspect it was a basic struggle for survival in increasingly worsening circumstances.

This wasn't as far as I recall, a particularly long book - probably 250 pages or fewer (standard for the time period).

Comment: This seems thin on plot for a novel; what was the conflict that drove the plot?  Oh, and you flipped to the back and read the end?  Shame on you. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember anything else.  Regarding looking at the end first, I have lived a pure life ever after to atone.

Comment: Sounds familiar. Does the protagonist live in a sealed community, but get out occasionally to look for diaries in the ruins?

Comment: I don't remember that bit but it easily could be a part of it.  I think the smoker was an older woman, very cynical, but I could be thinking of Selma and Patty Bouvier